# sql function case returns more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle

Going to use this query as a subquery, the problem is it returns many rows of duplicates. Tried to use COUNT() instead of exists, but it still returns a  multiple answer.
   Every table can only contain one record of superRef.

The below query I`ll use in SELECT col_a, [the CASE] From MyTable

```
SELECT CASE
        WHEN 
         EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM A WHERE 
            A_superRef = myTable.sysno AND A_specAttr = 'value')
        THEN 3
        WHEN     EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM B 
            INNER JOIN С ON С_ReferenceForB = B_sysNo WHERE C_superRef = myTable.sysno AND b_type = 2)
        THEN 2
        ELSE (SELECT C_intType FROM C 
            WHERE C_superRef = myTable.sysno)
        END
    FROM A, B, C
```

result:

```
3
3
3
3
3
3...
```

Comment: No join conditions? Perhaps you want UNION? Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: have you run the subqueries on their own? what do they return?

Comment: That's a cross join. With 1000 records per table you get 1 billion combinations. And for each row of these many records you query the tables again - without any reference to the record in question. This is certainly not what you are after. So what is it instead? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Union won`t work. every subquery return only one record or nothing

Comment: Still your query makes no sense. You look up whether a 1000001838012/value record exists in A. If so you show 3. For every cross join row. In the given example: 1 billion times value 3. So again: Tell us what you want to achieve. The query you've written is just horrorible.

Comment: I need it to return 3 just once, so I won`t get "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row" when use this query  SELECT col_a, [the CASE] From MyTable

Comment: Why do you select from `A, B, C` then (which is `A CROSS JOIN B CROSS JOIN C` with proper joins)? It seems you want to select `FROM DUAL` instead.

Comment: well, what would you suggest to select from?

Comment: I just suggested to select from **dual**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DUAL is what I needed, thanks to [Thorsten Kettner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2270762/thorsten-kettner)

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN 
     EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM A WHERE 
        A_superRef = 1000001838012)
    THEN 3
    WHEN     EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM B 
        INNER JOIN С ON С_ReferenceForB = B_sysNo AND C_superRef = 1000001838012 )
    THEN 2
    ELSE (SELECT C_type FROM C 
        WHERE C_superRef = 1000001838012)
    END
FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you did this? Because Im guessing you are getting an implicit full outer join A X B X C then running the case statement for each row in that result set.

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN 
     EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM A WHERE 
        A_superRef = 1000001838012)
    THEN 3
    WHEN     EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM B 
        INNER JOIN С ON С_ReferenceForB = B_sysNo AND C_superRef = 1000001838012 )
    THEN 2
    ELSE (SELECT C_type FROM C 
        WHERE C_superRef = 1000001838012)
    END
FROM ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A ) --This is a hack but should work in ANSI sql.
                                --Your milage my vary with different RDBMS flavors.
```

Comment: well that works! magic=) but should I use exactly table A? And according to the execution plan this gives better performance too ... And works for all of the cases

Comment: Er, if you want to select one pseudo row, select from `dual`. It is made for exactly this purpose. (In other DBMS you'd omit the `from` clause instead, but Oracle requires it and invented `dual` for that reason.) No need for a "hack". (Your solution even reads the whole table A completely unnecessarily.)

Comment: OP's query is no "full outer join" by the way (which would still join on criteria), but a cross join leading to a cartesian product.

Comment: Yes. I checked that out, indeed better. Sorry I just didn`t know about this DUAL table

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I suppose you are right it couldn't be an outer join if there is no join criteria ... the important part is the implicit join though.